# Insufficient code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a simple class that validates user input and assigns cases.

Class -

```
public with sharing class CaseAssign {
public Case c { get; set; }
public boolean choice(){

    if( (c.First_Selection__c == true && c.Second_Selection__c == true) || (c.First_Selection__c != true && c.Second_Selection__c != true) ){
    ApexPages.Message myCho = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Please select one checkbox:');
        apexpages.addmessage(myCho);
        return false;
        }

if((c.First_Selection__c == true && c.First_Topics__c == null)){
    ApexPages.Message myOpt1 = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Please select a Topic');
        apexpages.addmessage(myOpt1);
        return false;
        }

if((c.Second_Selection__c == true && (c.Branch__c == null || c.Office__c == null)) ){
  ApexPages.Message myOpt2 = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Please select both branch and office');
        apexpages.addmessage(myOpt2);
        return false;
  }

else {
        return true;
    }

}

public boolean allsel(){
    if(c.Aff__c == null || c.Email__c == null || c.Country__c == null || c.Zip_Code__c == null || c.Question__c == null ){
    ApexPages.Message mySel = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Please fill all the required information');
        apexpages.addmessage(mySel);
        return false;
        }
    else {
        return true;
}

}

public PageReference verify() {


    boolean sel = choice();
boolean asl = allsel();

     system.debug('---res is -->'+res);
if(sel == false || asl == false)
{
return null;
  }
else
{
String emailId = c.Email__c; 
     String queueName;

    if(c.First_Selection__c == true){
    c.Branch__c = null;
c.Office__c = null;
    queueName='Second Support';


         if(c.First_Topics__c == 'XYZ'){

             queueName='Third Support'; 
               }
          }
else if (c.Second_Selection__c == true ){
     c.First_Topics__c = null;
     queueName='First Support';
    }

    id queueGroupId= [Select Id from Group where type='Queue' and Name= :queueName].Id;
      c.origin = 'Web';
      c.ownerId = queueGroupId;
      c.status = 'Assigned';
      INSERT c;

          return (new pagereference('/apex/SurveyPage').setredirect(true));
         }

  }
}
```

Test Class -

```
@isTest
Private class CaseAssignTest{
static testmethod void myUnitTest(){

Test.startTest();

            CaseAssign CA = new CaseAssign();
            Case objC = new Case();
            objc.origin='web';
            objc.Email__c='Test1@gmail.com';
            objc.status='Assigned';
            objc.zip_code__c='23000'; 
            objc.country__c='United States';
            objc.First_Selection__c = true;
            objc.First_Topics__c = null;
            insert objC;

    Case objC3 = new Case();
            objc3.origin='Assigned';
            objc3.Email__c='Test4@gmail.com';
            objc3.status='Web';
            objc3.zip_code__c='23000'; 
            objc3.country__c='United States';
            objc3.Second_Selection__c = true;
            objc3.Office__c= 'cheese';
            objc3.Branch__c=null;
            insert objC3;


     try{ CA.choice()    }
             catch(exception e){}

    try{  CA.allsel();
             }
             catch(exception e){}
try{
             CA.verify();
             }
             catch(exception e){}
```

After reading thru previous posted questions i tried something for the apex page messages.

But no luck...
I get an error message assertion failed...

```
    Test.setCurrentPage(Page.caseassign);

    List<Apexpages.Message> msgs = ApexPages.getMessages();

    boolean isErrorMessage = false;

    for(Apexpages.Message msg : msgs){
        if (msg.getDetail().contains('Please select a Topic') )
            isErrorMessage  = true;
    }
    system.assert(isErrorMessage );

     Test.stopTest();
    }

 }
```

Any help is appreciated..thank you!

Comment: can put complete test class here

Comment: @SantanuBoral Hi, my complete test class is included in the question...

Comment: then, where you have added all these page message related code?

Comment: @SantanuBoral Hi, i didn't get you, i included the complete code for my class(contains the code for page message) and test class ( including the test coverage for apex page message that i tried with) in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create test data which could throw error.  For example: `'Please select one checkbox:'` error scenario.

```
CaseAssign CA = new CaseAssign();
List<Apexpages.Message> msgs = ApexPages.getMessages();

Case objC = new Case();
objc.origin='web';
objc.Email__c='Test1@gmail.com';
objc.status='Assigned';
objc.zip_code__c='23000'; 
objc.country__c='United States';
objc.First_Selection__c = true;
objc.Second_Selection__c  = true; //here both cannot be true
insert objC;
CA.c = objC;
CA.choice(); //it will throw error messages 'Please select one checkbox:'
boolean isErrorMessage = false;

//now retrieve the error messages
for(Apexpages.Message msg : msgs){
if (msg.getDetail().contains('Please select one checkbox')
    isErrorMessage  = true;
}
system.assert(isErrorMessage );
```

Now retrieve the Case record and update respective attributes to throw the error and the same way you can capture the error message and verify assert.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, same result, it says assertion failed...

Comment: I have tried to give you the logic to capturing the messages. You could debug and implement the code according to your need

Comment: updated the msg checking if clause

Comment: you know what, i removed the assertion and just creating the negative test data that mimics each page message increased the coverage, right now at 73%...and it shows no coverage for the verify() right from this line 'String emailId = c.Email__c;' to the end of the code, can you suggest something here?

Comment: creating the positive test data for the same along with Q assignment did the trick, appreciate your help man, thanks a ton!